# how to allow space?

Tags: jquery

the below javascript code prevent user to put all special character including "space".

1. through same function, I need to allow "space"..how to do this..please help
2. however user is unable to type any special character, but user can copy/paste special character. Is there any way to prevent this also...one way disable right click on page..any other way..please suggest!

   ```
   function isValidSearchText(evt) {
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
       if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90))
           return false;
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: i can suggest you to check the value of the input instead of the key code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if-statement from this

```
if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && ....
```

To this:

```
if (charCode != 32 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && ...
```